# Why my mesh does not connect?

Tags: modeling, mesh

can someone tell me why my mesh does not connect? Idk what is wrong.

### [image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure this is one vertex and not 2 overlapping vertices?

Comment: It was 2 vertices overalapping each other, thanks! This is my 1st model, where i dont follow youtube tutorial, so i did not realize. Thanks again for quick response! :)

Comment: Side note, I would suggest to move the [pole to the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dMYu.png).